# Extract only the integers from list (not the floats)

Tags: python, string, integer, extract

I have some problems with the following issue:

I have a string, which contains integers and floats. I fail to extract only the integers (NOT the floats!).

What i have (it is a string):

```
f=  "0:6.0 3:5.6 54:12.3 56:12.0"
```

How the result should be (not in a string form):

```
0,3,54,56
```

I searched on Google (and stack-overflow) which leads to this solution:

```
[int(s) for s in f.split() if s.isdigit()]
```

That leads to a empty list.

Other solutions like:

```
int(re.search(r'\d+', f).group())
```

Leads to "0 integers". Sorry i'm new but I really can't solve this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [.partition(':')](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
>>> s="0:6.0 3:5.6 54:12.3 56:12.0"
>>> [e.partition(':')[0] for e in s.split()]
['0', '3', '54', '56']
```

Then call `int` on those strings:

```
>>> [int(e.partition(':')[0]) for e in s.split()]
[0, 3, 54, 56]
```

Or,

```
>>> map(int, (e.partition(':')[0] for e in s.split()))
[0, 3, 54, 56]
```

And you can use the same method (with a slight change) to get the floats:

```
>>> map(float, (e.partition(':')[2] for e in s.split()))
[6.0, 5.6, 12.3, 12.0]
```

---

Fair question asked in comments: *Why use partition ? you can use int(split(":")[0])*

1. With `.partition` it is clear to all readers (including your future self) that you are looking at 1 split only. (Granted, you *could* use the 2 argument form of `split(delimiter, maxsplit)` but I think that is less clear for a single split...)
2. It is easier to test successful partitioning since partition *always* produces a three element tuple and you only need to test the truthiness of the element `tuple[1]`.
3. You can safely use `.partion` in tuple assignments of the form `lh,delimiter,rh=string.partion('delimiter')` where `lh, rh=string.split('delimiter')` will produce a `ValueError` if the delimiter is not found.
4. With the delimiter included in the resulting tuple, it is easier to reassemble the original string with `''.join(tuple_from_partion)` vs `split` since the delimiter in `split` is lost.
5. Why not?

Comment: Why use `partition` ? you can use `int(spit(":")[0])`

Comment: You can use `split(':')` if you prefer. To *me*, `partition` is more obvious that you are looking for a single delimiter vs `split` which suggests many (unless you use the form of `split('delimiter', maxsplit)` but then I have to look up is `maxsplit`  a keyword argument vs a positional argument and by that time I can already type `partition()`)  :-)

Comment: Great explanation @dawg .. Appreciate the time you took to write it...+1

Answer (score 1):

How about using the following regex:

```
import re

f =  "0:6.0 3:5.6 54:12.3 56:12.0"
answer = [int(x) for x in re.findall(r'\d{1,2}(?=:)', f)]
print(answer)
```

**Output**

```
[0, 3, 54, 56]
```

You can also achieve the same result using `map` instead of a list comprehension (as in @dawg's answer):

```
answer = map(int, re.findall(r'\d{1,2}(?=:)', f))
```

Comment: It only has a bug: e.g. when there is a integer with 100:2.3  (it wil print 10 in stead of 100). Is that fixable?

Comment: @Loesje changing to `\d{1,2,3}` will allow for 3 numeric digits

Comment: The pattern `\d{1,2,3}` is not doing what you think. It would be interpreted as one digit followed by the literal string `{1,2,3}`. You would use `\d{1,3}` for strings of digits between 1 and 3 digits long. Why limit the length of the digits at all? You can use `re.findall(r'\b(\d+):', f)`

Comment: That is what I should have said!